# Does a Lua Table / Array Beautifier exist?

Tags: lua

Considering all the json, xml formatters/beautifies out there, I’ve been unable to find one for Lua tables/arrays ?

The nuance here is that the output to beautify,  is from what i believe is a widely used table/array `dump` function - see below..

```
function dump(o)
    if type(o) == 'table' then
        local s = '{ '
        for k,v in pairs(o) do
            if type(k) ~= 'number' then 
                k = '"'..k..'"' 
            end
            s = s .. '['..k..'] = ' .. dump(v) .. ','
        end
        return s .. '} '
    else
        return tostring(o)
    end
end
```

What I’m thinking is something like this.

A table dumped looks like this.

```
{[1] = ,[2] = { ["attr"] = { [1] = code,[2] = remaining,[3] = resetdate,["remaining"] = 990,["resetdate"] = 1638614242,["code"] = 200,} ,["tag"] = success,} ,[3] = ,["attr"] = { } ,["tag"] = prowl,}
```

I’d love a beautifier that could present it like this..

```
{
[1] = ,
[2] = { 
    ["attr"] = { 
    [1] = code,
    [2] = remaining,
    [3] = resetdate,
    ["remaining"] = 990,
    ["resetdate"] = 1638614242,
    ["code"] = 200,
    } ,
    ["tag"] = success,
    } ,
[3] = ,
    ["attr"] = { } ,
    ["tag"] = prowl,
}
```

Comment: what stops you from implementing one yourself? I mean searching for something like this and asking this question probably took more time than adding a few tabs and linebreaks while tranversing over a table

Answer (score 2):

An example of such processing, you can correct the little things yourself:

```
function dump(o,level)
    level = level or 1
    if type(o) == 'table' then
        local s = {}
        s[1] = '{ '
        for k,v in pairs(o) do
            if type(k) ~= 'number' then 
                k = '"'..k..'"' 
            end
            s[#s+1] = string.rep('\t',level).. '['..k..'] = ' .. dump(v, level+1) .. ','
        end
        s[#s+1] = string.rep('\t',level) .. '} '
        return table.concat(s , "\n")
    else
        return tostring(o or 'nil')
    end
end
local t = {[1] = nil,[2] = { ["attr"] = { [1] = code,[2] = remaining,[3] = resetdate,["remaining"] = 990,["resetdate"] = 1638614242,["code"] = 200,} ,["tag"] = success,} ,[3] = nil,["attr"] = { } ,["tag"] = prowl,}

print (dump(t))
```

result:

```
{ 
    ["attr"] = { 
        } ,
    [2] = { 
        ["attr"] = { 
            ["remaining"] = 990,
            ["code"] = 200,
            ["resetdate"] = 1638614242,
            } ,
        } ,
    }
```

you should also be aware that empty initialization values (like [3] =,) will throw an error, and generally zero data (like [3] = resetdate ) will be discarded in the dump, because assigning nil means deleting the table element.